# 1611- Fan x missing, Fan Solution Not Sufficient in HP ProLiant DL380 G6

Tags: windows-server-2003, hp, hp-proliant, power-supply-unit, fan

I have HP ProLiant DL380 G6 server. It is showing following errors.

```
1611- Fan 1 missing,
1611- Fan 2 missing,
1611- Fan 3 missing,
1611- Fan 4 missing,
```

Fan Solution Not Sufficient,
1615- Power Supply Failure or Power Supply Unplugged in bay 1

I checked that all fans are working.

Out of 4, 2 fans are running. When I firmly inserted one of 2 fans which were not running, it started running and my server also started. but after sometime, fan stopped, but server is running.

So, please guide me, what could be problems and their solutions(whether its hardware problem or related to power supply).

Answer (score 2):

Dude... you need to have working parts. There's a minimum number of fans required for that server to POST. You mention four fans. There are six slots. You probably only have one processor, which means that you need THREE running fans of FOUR to operate in order for the system to behave.

```
At POST:
o The BIOS performs an orderly shutdown if two or more fans have failed.
o The server performs an immediate shutdown if it detects a critical temperature level.
```

Please see the [Maintenance Guide for the DL380 G6](http://www.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01705597.pdf).

Also, fix the power supply.

Answer (score 0):

Fans show inoperative even though they run?  Could be bad sensor or backplane.  Obviously if "firmly inserting" the fan makes it run, even if temporarily, there is a bad connection or possibly a bad retainer/clip.

One of the first things I do in our DC servers when something "fails" is reseat anything between the "bad" component and the motherboard connection, including the component and the motherboard connection themselves. Especially on older hardware.   Although, I've noticed or oldest hardware had the least problems (perhaps because they're used less).  We still have Compaq branded ProLiant servers.